# Python Code Isn't Reading Serial Data Properly

Tags: python, serialization

So I am writing a program to Read and Write data to and from a Serial Port.  Said port is setup where I know the specific byte codes it sends for the different states it is in.  However, I am having an issue with my Python script that should be reading the Serial data and printing it to the screen.

Here is the setup for the Port, and my `ReadLine` method:

```
class SerialCommunicator:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    
        self.port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
        self.portSettings = {
            'baudrate' : 57600,
            'bytesize' : 8,
            'parity' : 'N',
            'stopbits' : 1,
            'timeout' : 0,
            'inter_byte_timeout' : None,
            'write_timeout' : None,
            'xonxoff' : False,
            'rtscts' : False,
            'dsrdtr' : False }
        self.port.apply_settings(self.portSettings)
        while True:
            output = self.ReadLine()
            if (output != ''):
                print(output)

    def ReadLine(self):
        readValue = ""
        isReading = True
        while isReading:
            currentRead = self.port.read()
            currentRead = currentRead.decode()
            readValue += currentRead
            if currentRead == '\r' or currentRead = '':
                isReading = False
                return readValue
```

So when I run this code, the output I am expecting a a garbled mess.  I am expecting two output strings from the serial port running on standby:

```
T12F8B0A2200F8
```

and

```
T1610FFA20
```

The second output is always coming out correctly.  However the first one either has the head of the code cut off, or it's sliced in the middle, or it's tail is missing.  I need the code to be properly intact because I use the code in reading what state the device is in.  What could be my problem?

EDIT:  For those curious, yes I have tried adjusting the baudrate.  However with a baudrate higher than 57600 I get no output data at all.

Comment: Isn't this related to your ``timeout``? Just like with sockets you can end up getting a partial message.

Comment: Yes, I kind of just realized this.  Thank you :)

Comment: Might i add that there is a typo in your very last `if` statement, it should be `or currentread == '':`. Also, your while loop in `ReadLine()` is using a variable `isReading ` that you don't really need. You can just loop `while True`, as you break the loop in your if-statement by `return`-ing

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my problem was with my `timeout` value.  Setting `'timeout' : 1` fixed my problem :)